# Вывод продвинутого рейтинга

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица MySQL(users), там данные - id, name, points. Мне нужно получить 3 строчки: 1 человек, который по баллам больше, я и 1 человек, который по баллам меньше.[image: Пример]
Прошу помощи, как это сделать?

Comment: Не понимаю минусующих и тем более закрывающих, проблема опечаткой явно не вызвана и задание явно не учебное, плюс к этому ТС привел свой код в ответе, так что работа явно не за автора.

Comment: @Mike Никто наверное не обращает внимание, что автор вопроса и ответа, который в самом низу, одно лицо. Поддерживаю, не надо закрывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А запрос в MySQL оказался довольно не тривиальным:

```
select U.*
  from tab_users U
  join (
    select counter,id from tab_users
     where counter >= (select counter from tab_users where id=@my_id)
     order by (id=@my_id), counter limit 1
  ) P
    on     U.counter < P.counter
       or (U.counter >= P.counter and U.id in(P.id, @my_id))
 order by (U.id!=P.id), U.counter desc
 limit 3
```

Подзапрос P получает рейтинг и id записи у которой рейтинг больше, либо такой же как у основной записи ("Я"). При этом, если записей с таким же рейтингом, как у основной несколько, берется любая из них, кроме основной. Если записей с большим или таким же рейтингом найдено не будет, то возьмется основная запись.

После этого к подзапросу подбираются все записи с меньшим либо равным рейтингом. Причем если рейтинг равен, то надо брать строго одну запись с id, найденном в подзапросе P либо основную. Записи сортируются так, что бы запись из подзапроса P обязательно оказалась первой.

При таком подходе основная запись оказывается в середине. В случае если рейтинг основной записи максимален ("Я top 1") получим так же 3 записи, при этом основная запись будет первой. В случае же, если основная запись в самом низу рейтинга, то запрос выдает всего 2 записи - предыдущую и основную (если этот момент не устраивает, надо еще поработать с условиями подзапроса P что бы получить еще резервную запись, для такого случая).

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0a1e/1)

Вариант 2: пронумеровать все записи и найти нужные по номерам:

```
select *
  from (
   select *, @n:=@n+1 num, @my_num:=if(id=@my_id,@n,@my_num)
     from tab_users, (select @n:=0, @my_num:=0) x
    order by counter
  ) X
  where num between @my_num-1 and @my_num+1
```

Comment: Да, не тривиально. Почему бы не попробовать с lead/lag?

Comment: @0xdb потому что это MySQL ... хотя пронумеровать наверное можно попробовать ...

Comment: В смысле, не тот [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)?

Comment: @0xdb В смысле, что в MySQL нет оконных функций как таковых и lead/lag в частности. Но эмуляция row_number на переменных прошла успешно (ответ дописал), так возможно проще, если не считать, что запросу придется пройти всю таблицу в обязательном порядке...

Comment: Ну да, в ссылке 8-ка, не обратил внимания.

Comment: @0xdb Не знал, что у них уже 8 есть. просто везде сейчас 5ю ветку используют. На наличие 8 на хостингах пока надеяться рано.

Comment: Да, с гуглей попал и не сразу заметил заметил, что это RC, то есть светлое будущее))

Answer (score 1):

Сделал очень криво, но работает.

```
$qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `counter` FROM `users` WHERE `job` = 0 ORDER BY `counter` DESC");
                    echo '<h3>Позиция</h3>';
                    echo '<table border="1" class="table" id="utable">';
                    echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th>№</th>';
                    echo '<th>Ф.И.О.</th>';
                    echo '<th>Баллы</th>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</thead>';
                    echo '<tbody>';
                    $i=0;
                    $iidata = Array();
                    while($idata = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){
                        array_push($iidata, $idata);
                    }
                    foreach($iidata as $val){
                        if($val['id']==$data['id']){
                          if($i-1<0){
                          echo '<tr id="active">';
                          echo '<td>' . ($i+1) . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $val['name'] . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $val['counter'] . '</td>';
                          echo '</tr>';
                          echo '<tr>';
                          echo '<td>' . ($i+2) . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i+1]['name'] . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i+1]['counter'] . '</td>';
                          echo '</tr>';
                          echo '<tr>';
                          echo '<td>' . ($i+3) . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i+2]['name'] . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i+2]['counter'] . '</td>';
                          echo '</tr>';
                          }else{
                          echo '<tr>';
                          echo '<td>' . ($i) . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i-1]['name'] . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i-1]['counter'] . '</td>';
                          echo '</tr>';
                          echo '<tr id="active">';
                          echo '<td>' . ($i+1) . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $val['name'] . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $val['counter'] . '</td>';
                          echo '</tr>';
                          echo '<tr>';
                          echo '<td>' . ($i+2) . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i+1]['name'] . '</td>';
                          echo '<td>' . $iidata[$i+1]['counter'] . '</td>';
                          echo '</tr>';
                          }
                        }
                        $i++;
```

Спасибо, кто хотел помочь!

Comment: У вас в коде возникнут проблемы, в случае если основная запись первая или последняя в выборке. произойдет обращение за пределы массива по индексу